# How to calculate length of string in a tuple in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given a list of tuples, where the 1st element of the tuple is an integer and the second element is a string,

```
scala> val tuple2 : List[(Int,String)] = List((1,"apple"),(2,"ball"),(3,"cat"),(4,"doll"),(5,"eggs"))
tuple2: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,apple), (2,ball), (3,cat), (4,doll), (5,eggs))
```

I want to print the numbers where the corresponding string length is 4.

Can this be done in one line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you need `.collect` which is filter+map**

given your input,

```
scala> val input : List[(Int,String)] = List((1,"apple"),(2,"ball"),(3,"cat"),(4,"doll"),(5,"eggs"))
input: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,apple), (2,ball), (3,cat), (4,doll), (5,eggs))
```

filter those of length 4,

```
scala> input.collect { case(number, string) if string.length == 4 => number}
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5)
```

**alternative solution using `filter` + `map`,**

```
scala> input.filter { case(number, string) => string.length == 4 }
            .map { case (number, string) => number}
res4: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you `filter` and `print` as below

```
tuple2.filter(_._2.length == 4).foreach(x => println(x._1))
```

You should have output as

```
2
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @prayagupd answer using **collect**. But **foldLeft** is the one of my favourite function in Scala! you can use foldLeft:

```
  scala> val input : List[(Int,String)] = List((1,"apple"),(2,"ball"),(3,"cat"),(4,"doll"),(5,"eggs"))
   input: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,apple), (2,ball), (3,cat), (4,doll), (5,eggs))

  scala> input.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){case (acc, (n,str)) => if(str.length ==4) acc :+ n  else acc}
   res3: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension as follows,

```
for ((i,s) <- tuple2 if s.size == 4) yield i
```

which for the example above delivers

```
List(2, 4, 5)
```

Note we pattern match and extract the elements in each tuple and filter by string size. To print a list consider for instance `aList.foreach(println)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
tuple2.filter(_._2.size==4).map(_._1)
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> val tuple2 : List[(Int,String)] = List((1,"apple"),(2,"ball"),(3,"cat"),(4,"doll"),(5,"eggs"))
tuple2: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,apple), (2,ball), (3,cat), (4,doll), (5,eggs))

scala> tuple2.filter(_._2.size==4).map(_._1)
res261: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5)

scala>
```